# How to know if a computer which has python installed uses the command 'python' or 'python3' to run a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I create a python file (file1.py) which executes another python script (file2.py), I need to know the correct 'python' command usage to execute the file2 from inside file1.py and use the correct variable recognized by the system. For example, the user must know the correct python command to run file1.py:

```
python ./file1.py  OR  python3 ./file1.py  [USER must know what to use]
```

file1.py executes file2.py in a separate subprocess:

```
python ./file2.py  OR  python3 ./file2.py [The USER should not care what's inside file2.py]
```

Is there a way to know which 'python' command would work for a system in file2.py? If 'python' is recognized by the system, the command with 'python3' will return an error, and vice-versa. I need to update file1.py to use the correct 'python' automatically, so that file2.py can run smoothly from system to system

Comment: What do you mean "file1.py contains: `python ./file2.py`"?

Comment: If you want a path to the *executable* use `sys.executable`. This can be used to start a subprocess using the same interpreter

Comment: i updated the question, file1.py executes file2.py in a separate subprocess

Comment: Typically, you shouldn't use `python file2.py` inside `file1.py`. Instead, `file1.py` should assume the `file2.py` has been installed correctly as an executable script and execute it as `./file2.py`.

Comment: When you tell us your source code does something, *just give us the code*. In any case, what I said already seems to stand, you don't *care* what command the user used at the shell, instead, just use `sys.executable` which just gives you the [absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : using sys.executable seems to work for my case. The file2.py invocation from file1.py is correct with this.